# Properly overloading >> Operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I couldn't find a proper example of how to do it properly.

The following code is written in the FAQ.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, T& obj)
{
  // read obj from stream

if( /* no valid object of T found in stream */ )
    is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

return is;
}
```

How do I check if "no valid object of T found in stream" ?

Comment: It depends on what `T` is, and what you expect to be in the input stream.

Comment: Let's say it a simple variable, like int for example.

Comment: Then it's a simple `if (!(is >> int_variable)) { /* failure */ }`. The `failbit` will already be set for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

Save the current possition in input stream by:

```
streampos pos = is.tellg()
```

Read the data from stream to some char buffer:

```
char tmp_buf[expected_size];
read(tmp_buf, expected_size);

// try to create a temporary object from read data
T tmp_obj = T::fromCharBuffer(tmp_buf) // you need to implement that

// If you get a valid object copy it to the destination
obj = tmp_obj

// in case of error revert previous stream position
if (error)
    is.seekg(pos)

return is
```

### Ok, ignore all above, I was just wrong:

This topic can help you better:

> [What's the right way to overload the stream operators << >> for my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351972/whats-the-right-way-to-overload-the-stream-operators-for-my-class)

More elegant solution:

Your have to interprate/validate the data for particular class so you need to implement this functionality somewhere. You have 3 options:

1. in particular class
2. in some base class
3. in friend class of your particular class (best option)

My implementation of approach no.3

```
class SomeClassParser:
{
     // implement the functionality of creating SomeClass from stream.
     static SomeClass fromStream(ifstream &if)
     {
         // do your stream reading here and return SomeClass object
         // or throw parsing exception
     }

};

class SomeClass:
{
    public:
        friend SomeClassParser;
        // points to the Parser class
        typedef SomeClassParser Parser;
        ...
};

template<typename T>
ifstream& operator<<(ifstream &if, T& obj)
{
    // do your type independent work, depending on your needs:
    // logging, stream recovery, error handling etc;
    // I'm not telling it's good or bad approach to recover the stream after failure
    // do what you need here

    // save stream
    streampos pos = is.tellg()
    try
    {
        obj = T::Parser::fromStream(if);
    }
    catch (int e):
    {
        // restore stream
        is.seekg(pos);
    }
}
```

With this solution you will not destroy your old object in case the parsing error ocurrs.

Comment: What would you imply from `expected_size` regarding the validity of a particular type (remember that is just text read in)? Also how should be `expected_size` set if the input can be `1`, `10` or `100000`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What can you tell about my current solution?